# how to make relativelayout outside of listview scrolling with that listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

i have a xml file contains some UI elements and a listview, above the listview there is relativelayout , i want when scrolling the listview , the relativelayout scrolls with it, how?

Comment: is listview contains header ? maybe i put the relaytive layout inside that header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ListView.addHeaderView(View view)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29).

Note that in this case you should exclude your `RelativeLayout` from xml and create it in runtime. Also `addHeaderView` **MUST** be called before `setAdapter`.

**UPDATE**

just extract `RelativeLayout` to a separate xml file (e.g. `header.xml`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/orderMeal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:id="@+id/tv_restaurant_description_orderMeal"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/order_meal" />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/favorite"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"

        android:drawableTop="@drawable/favorite"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and then inflate it in the code:

```
lv_restaurantInformation = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_restaurant_description_information);
lv_restaurantInformation.addHeaderView(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.header, null));
```

Comment: like this ? `View v = findViewById(R.layout.simple_list_item_header);
  lv_restaurantInformation.addHeaderView(v);
  lv_restaurantInformation.setAdapter(informationAdapter);`

Comment: i got exceptoin , i updated the quesiton with the activity code, the addheader is at `initialize` function

Comment: Just make sure that you do the above before you findViewById items in your header XML. I put it just before setAdapter and it crashed.